# How to get bluetooth device data in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXHLX.png

Is there a way in C# to get these settings (specifically the 'Direction') for a COM port?

I've tried using the SerialDevice class and searching "Win32_SerialPort" but neither have any properties that have to do with direction.

The two COM ports are both being used by the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think that you're asking a non-question about a non-problem, that is, there is absolutely no need (afaik) to know the 'direction' of the virtual port.
You have to use sockets to deal with Bluetooth under Win7, not directly through the COM ports:
you are either a 'server', receiving calls from other devices (then implicitely using an incoming COM port)
or you are a 'client' emitting calls (then implicitely using an outgoing COM port).
But once again, this is **not** the way you should program your code: it will fail most of the time, give you headaches, believe me ;)